# Android TV :Show Row Title always

Tags: android, android-tv

How do I get the title of the individual rows to always appear instead of only when it is selected? Like the example here in Youtube app, "Uploads" and "Popular Uploads" should always be seen.

[image]

Comment: When you build movie info add that title also.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514275/1759443), but the general gist is:

> I was able to achieve this affect by calling `setExpand(true)` as the first line of my `onCreateView()` in my `RowsFragment`.
>
> If you want to lock this effect forever, you can override `setExpand(...)` in your `RowsFragment` and just call `super.setExpand(true)`. I believe you'll still need the initial call in `onCreateView()` though.

Comment: Are you using a custom RowFragment for this? When I try to setExpand(true), getRowFragment returns null

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom RowsFragment. The class that those calls go into is your subclass of `RowsFragment`. If you're unfamiliar with leanback, you can check out [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase) and [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) provided by the leanback team.