# Disable row scaling / expand in BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I have not found any documentation how to disable the row scaling when switching the focus from the Headers to the Fragments in a BrowseFragment.

Leanback version 24.2.0

The BrowseFragment has a function `enableMainFragmentScaling` which solves the problem partially. The images now have the full size, but the titles are still not expanded like they are in the PlayStore App, Youtube app. The expand (without animation) when focusing a row.

What i did so far:

- `enableMainFragmentScaling(false);` in BrowseFragment
- `setExpand(false);` in the nested RowsFragments. But it didn't change anything.

The Code is very similar to the demo leanback project. But there they have row scaling enabled. [Demo on Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/tree/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve this affect by calling `setExpand(true)` as the first line of my `onCreateView()` in my `RowsFragment`.

If you want to lock this effect forever, you can override `setExpand(...)` in your `RowsFragment` and just call `super.setExpand(true)`. I believe you'll still need the initial call in `onCreateView()` though.

Comment: If you override and always return true... I can confirm you don't need to call this method in onCreateView.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in `BrowseSupportFragment`

Answer (score 0):

You should call to

```
enableRowScaling(false);
```

on the `onActivityCreated()` method of your **MainFragment.java** class

Comment: This has been deprecated.  Use @Kyle Venn approach.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of `BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapterProvider` try disabling the scaling before returning the fragment adapter.

```
    override fun getMainFragmentAdapter(): BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapter<*> {
        val mainFragmentAdapter = MainFragmentAdapter(this)
        mainFragmentAdapter.isScalingEnabled = false
        return mainFragmentAdapter
    }
```